# Any good ways to update just one part of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, real-time, html

New to webpage design, I am doing some finite volume analysis to do flow simulation. I have a log file that records the residuals as time is marching. I want to show the real time residual on my webpage. I am wondering what is the way to update a number or a picture on a webpage without updating the whole webpage? Thanks

Could anyone give me a simple link with an easy tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: That is done via Ajax.  There are many, many ways of implementing Ajax functionality depending on your platform, your choice of tools, etc.  The subject is far too broad to answer here, but as a starting point, I'd google "Ajax", learn what you can, and come back with more specific questions.  The big question comes not in learning Ajax, but in how to architecture the whole solution.  How to push the data (how to serve it, for that matter) so that the Ajax on the web page can read it, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering what is the way to update a number or a picture on a webpage without updating the whole webpage?

Yes, there is. Using JavaScript with [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Using AJAX you can call the server to fetch either data or whole HTML fragments and with JavaScript replace portions of the page.